# Is Angular caching my object?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm trying to build a drag & drop list with ctrl/shift selection in Angular. For some reason, when I attempt to load my template / directive, angular uses the last array loaded at any given point. What I mean by this is, if I load two arrays, each in separate `<ul>` elements, it will use the second one for both of them. Overall, it's pretty confusing why it happens.

[See my fiddle here](http://plnkr.co/edit/K2So31?p=preview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing the same scope attribute twice:

```
ng-init="itemList=itemsInTrash"
...
ng-init="itemList=itemsThatAreReal"
```

So, once the template has been initialized, this `itemList` variable references the `itemsThatAreReal` array, and the two included templates thus display this array.

Comment: So, what do you recommend I do to make my template usable?

Comment: Use your directive directly, without going though an ng-include.

Comment: Almost. But your directive needs to use an isolated scope, instead of using the scope of its parent template. See http://plnkr.co/edit/dx5vxPSgvXc6G8S6nIBC?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I couldn't quite remember how to do this.

Comment: hey - just one more thing. For some reason I can no longer select my items. I've tried to make my scope transcluded and access the parent for selection, but that doesn't seem to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I just passed the function as another parameter in the directive ([here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xBVkTtQrTMLXeMD7xNAw?p=preview) if you're interested). It works.